# convert from string object to binary value python

Tags: python, string, binary

I have a string that hold a binary number as a string

```
string = '0b100111'
```

I want to have that value not be a string type but a value (pseudo-code)

```
bin(string) = 0b100111
```

Any pythoners know an easy way to do this?

It is all part of this code for a Codecademy: (After answer implemented)

```
def flip_bit(number,n):
    if type(number)==type('s'):
        number = int(number,2)
    mask=(0b1<<n-1)
    print bin(mask)
    print mask
    desired = bin(number^mask)
    return desired
flip_bit('0b111', 2)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: convert from a string object to a binary value or integer.

Comment: The only place your `bin()` function is used in your sample code it takes a numeric argument, not a string. So I would suggest that the bin() function is intended to render a string representation of a binary value, while your question appears to imply the reverse.

Comment: Does the exercise actually require the use of character strings, or are your functions allowed to work on integer operands (which appears to be the case, since conversion from a string is optional)? I ask because the normal way to handle bitwise operations is using integer values along with the bitwise logical operators (& - and; | - or; ~ - not; and ^ - exclusive or). These are much more efficient than string operations.

Comment: Does nobody else have a problem with the title not appearing to match the accepted answer at all? Feels like it should be "convert from string representation of binary into decimal" to me...or at least "convert from binary string into decimal"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about calling `int` function with base `2`?

```
>>>s = '0b100111'
>>>b = int(s, 2)
>>>print b
39
```

Comment: O... its a great way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can make it binary by putting a b before the quotes:

```
>>> s = b'hello'
>>> s.decode()
'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that making it as idealised in your question is impossible. As what you want is a a series of characters, it can only be a string (or you could convert it to an integer). But it is still workable as a number with built in functions- for example:

```
num1 = '0b0110'
num1 = '0b0101'

result = int(num1, 2) + int(num2, 2)
print(bin(result))
```

The only way you could have that synatx in your code is if that binary number became a name itself. Python only supports the manipulation of numbers in base 10, as it only interprets number inputs in that format. Otherwise it is a string within which numbers cannot be manipulated.

Comment: Python normally REPRESENTS numbers in decimal, but internally it traditionally uses binary (base 2) formats for integer and floating-point numbers, not decimal (though there is the `decimal` module for financial arithmetic and other fixed-point applications).